# Get MIME type from filename extension and displaying them on blade views

Tags: php, laravel

I have an album that has a collection of photos and videos. I need to display them on my blade view. Files are being saved on my s3 bucket

```
| id | album_id | album_content  | sort  |
|----|----------|----------   - -|-------|
| 1  | 1        | name1.jpg      | 1    |
| 2  | 1        | name2.mp4      | 2    |
| 3  | 2        | name3.png      | 3    |
```

What I did so far is this:

```
@foreach($all_photos as $images)
            @foreach ($images->images as $photo)
                @if (pathinfo($photo->photo_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'png' ||
                    pathinfo($photo->photo_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'jpg' ||
                    pathinfo($photo->photo_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'jpeg')
                   <img src="{{$photo->photo_name}}">             
                @endif                 
                @if (pathinfo($photo->photo_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'mp4' ||
                pathinfo($photo->photo_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'mpeg' ||
                pathinfo($photo->photo_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'mov' || 
                pathinfo($photo->photo_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'avi')
                <video src="{{$photo->photo_name}}"></video>
                @endif
            @endforeach         
            @endforeach
```

Its working as intended but I know there are better ways to do this. I tried using mime_content_type but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from `File` facade, and get mime type from it's `mimetype()` method.

```
\File::mimeType($path_of_the_file);
```

Or using `\Storage` facade

```
\Storage::mimeType($path_of_the_file);
```

You can also get metadata of any file using `getMetaData()` method of storage facade

```
\Storage::getMetaData($path_of_the_file);
```

#### Update:

You can use regex to check if it's an image or a video type

```
preg_match_all('/image\/\w+/', \File::mimeType($photo->photo_name))
```

[Here is a list of all mimetypes](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Do you have any example where can I use this?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer but it's not working as expected. I get zero results using preg_match_all

Comment: @Jeano I've updated it again. `$photo->photo_name` was replaced with `\File::mimeType($photo->photo_name)` as it was a subtle mistake.